# iOS UITextField custom keyboard

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, custom-view, becomefirstresponder, inputview

I've a custom keyboard view on my app positioned at the bottom of my screen, it's based on Fabrizio Prosperi's FPNumberPadView.

I also have a couple of UITextFields, I want this keyboard to ALWAYS be on screen, whether a textfield has the focus or not.

that is working, BUT, regardless of the position I initially assign to the keyboard on the screen, as soon as I tap on the first textfield (and becomes the first responder), it disappears and immediately slides into the screen as the regular system keyboard would.

This is what I want to get rid of. I want the keyboard at the bottom from the get go and as I tap the textfields they receive the characters from this custom keyboard.

Any tips / link / help on how to accomplish this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I don't think it's a good idea to have your keyboard on the screen all the time. I'm pretty sure it's against Apple guidelines.

In order to achieve it anyway, a solution would be to have an invisible (hidden and/or out of the view) textfield that becomes a "firstresponder" after one of the other textfields resigns its firstresponder role.

Comment: Nicolas, thanks for the idea! regarding the app itself, it's KIND OF a calculator, you want a numeric keyboard at all times. however, this is for an engineering calculator where more than one variable is needed for a specific non-linear equation. I want the user to just open the app and start inputting numbers right away.